# Jackson serialization how to not show class and fields names

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a way using Jackson , in a serialization process , to **not** print 
1.the class name (the constructor name)
2.the field name (meaning to print only the field value)

```
    public class Test
{


    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws JsonMappingException
     * @throws JsonGenerationException
     */
    public void work(final ObjectMapper mapper) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        RestrictedAndVat restrictedAndVat = new RestrictedAndVat();
        restrictedAndVat.setRate(BigDecimal.valueOf(20));
        restrictedAndVat.setRestricted(true);
        final CountryRestrictedAndVat countryRestrictedAndVat1 = new CountryRestrictedAndVat();
        countryRestrictedAndVat1.setCountryCode("UK");
        countryRestrictedAndVat1.setRestrictedAndVat(restrictedAndVat);

        final ProductCountryRestrictedAndVat productCountryRestrictedAndVat = new ProductCountryRestrictedAndVat();
        final List<CountryRestrictedAndVat> list = new ArrayList<CountryRestrictedAndVat>();
        list.add(countryRestrictedAndVat1);

        productCountryRestrictedAndVat.setCountryRestrictedAndVat(list);
        LOG.info("Json:" + serialiseJson(productCountryRestrictedAndVat, mapper));

    }

    private <DATA> String serialiseJson(final DATA pojoData, final ObjectMapper mapper)
            throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {

        final StringWriter jsonWriter = new StringWriter();
        mapper.writeValue(jsonWriter, pojoData);
        return jsonWriter.toString().trim();
    }

}

public class ProductCountryRestrictedAndVat
{


    @JsonProperty(value = "crv", required = false)
    private List<CountryRestrictedAndVat> countryRestrictedAndVat;

    /**
     * @return the countryRestrictedAndVat
     */
    public List<CountryRestrictedAndVat> getCountryRestrictedAndVat()
    {
        return countryRestrictedAndVat;
    }

    /**
     * @param countryRestrictedAndVat
     *           the countryRestrictedAndVat to set
     */
    public void setCountryRestrictedAndVat(final List<CountryRestrictedAndVat> countryRestrictedAndVat)
    {
        this.countryRestrictedAndVat = countryRestrictedAndVat;
    }




}


    public class RestrictedAndVat
    {


        @JsonProperty("vat")
        @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        private BigDecimal rate;

        @JsonProperty("restricted")
        private boolean restricted;

        /**
         * @return the rate
         */
        public BigDecimal getRate()
        {
            return rate;
        }

        /**
         * @param rate
         *           the rate to set
         */
        public void setRate(final BigDecimal rate)
        {
            this.rate = rate;
        }

        /**
         * @return the restricted
         */
        public boolean isRestricted()
        {
            return restricted;
        }

        /**
         * @param restricted
         *           the restricted to set
         */
        public void setRestricted(final boolean restricted)
        {
            this.restricted = restricted;
        }

    }

    public class CountryRestrictedAndVat
    {



        @JsonProperty("country")
        private String countryCode;


        @JsonProperty(value = "rv", required = false)
        private RestrictedAndVat restrictedAndVat;


        /**
         * @return the countryCode
         */
        public String getCountryCode()
        {
            return countryCode;
        }


        /**
         * @param countryCode
         *           the countryCode to set
         */
        public void setCountryCode(final String countryCode)
        {
            this.countryCode = countryCode;
        }


        /**
         * @return the restrictedAndVat
         */
        public RestrictedAndVat getRestrictedAndVat()
        {
            return restrictedAndVat;
        }


        /**
         * @param restrictedAndVat
         *           the restrictedAndVat to set
         */
        public void setRestrictedAndVat(final RestrictedAndVat restrictedAndVat)
        {
            this.restrictedAndVat = restrictedAndVat;
        }

    }
```

the output is :
Json:{"crv":[{"country":"UK","rv":{"vat":20,"restricted":true}}]}

I want it to be :
Json:[{"UK":{"vat":20,"restricted":true}}]

Comment: The output of what? You're never serializing or printing anything in the code you posted.

Comment: So you're serializing a class, rather than an instance of the class? That doesn't make sense. Post a complete example reproducing the problem.

Comment: this is not a problem . This is a question :
Is there a way using Jackson , in a serialization process , to not print 1.the class name (the constructor name) 2.the field name (meaning to print only the field value)

Comment: Yes, that's the default behavior. Doing the obvious thing would get you that result. So you're not doing the obvious thing. But since you won't post what you're doing, we can't explain.

Comment: I edited my question . Please look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, using a custom serializer.

Annotate your `CountryRestrictedAndVat` class with

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CountryRestrictedAndVatSerializer.class)
```

Remove the `@JsonProperty` annotations.

And write the serializer:

```
public class CountryRestrictedAndVatSerializer extends JsonSerializer<CountryRestrictedAndVat> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(CountryRestrictedAndVat value,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField(value.getCountryCode(), value.getRestrictedAndVat());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it work . But actually I need another level of ProductCountryRestrictedAndVat that hold a list of CountryRestrictedAndVat (see above I changed the question code) , and again - no need to print the class name.I tried to extend your approach but with no success ..

Comment: ok I found : 
  gen.writeStartArray();
  for (final CountryRestrictedAndVat countryRestrictedAndVat : value.getCountryRestrictedAndVat())
  {
   gen.writeStartObject();
   gen.writeObjectField(countryRestrictedAndVat.getCountryCode(), countryRestrictedAndVat.getRestrictedAndVat());
   gen.writeEndObject();
  }
  gen.writeEndArray();